# Stop all jQuery before changing iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, permission-denied

I have a script with a previous and next button (and other controls outside iFrame) that repopulates an iFrame with each button click. This works great except when I am fading images inside an iFrame and change the content while its still in the process. The issue I have is in IE 10 and 11. Seems fine in non-IE browsers.

I have stripped down the code to make it simple to see what is going on. I basically I fade an image from outside the iFrame like:

```
var iframe = $('#iframe').contents();
$('#imageFading',iframe).fadeTo(750,1.0);
```

I change the iFrame content like:

```
var html = "Some HTML Content here";
var iframe = $('#iFrame').get(0);
iframe = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;
iframe.document.open();
iframe.document.write(html);
iframe.document.close();
```

If the iFrame content is being changed while the image is still fading, I get the error:

```
SCRIPT70: Permission denied
File: jquery.min.js, Line: 4, Column: 928
```

This error keeps outputting in the console until I refresh or close the page. I am using jQuery 1.11.2.

When I used the uncompressed version its line 6999, which is:

```
} else if ( tween.elem.style && ( tween.elem.style[ jQuery.cssProps[ tween.prop ] ] != null || jQuery.cssHooks[ tween.prop ] ) ) {
```

I have tried putting the fadeTo in a try/catch and using jQuery's clearQueue().

Comment: What `js` is at `File: jquery.min.js, Line: 4, Column: 928` ? Tried removing element before changing content of `iframe` ?

Comment: I have put the details of the line above from the uncompressed version. I have tried removing the specific elements and all elements before using jQuery's remove and overwriting using html function. No luck.

Comment: Try `.stop(true, true)` before adjusting `iframe` contents , see http://api.jquery.com/stop/#stop-clearQueue-jumpToEnd

Comment: Thanks, just found that actually and it works.

Comment: I'll give you the answer if you post one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`.stop(true, true)`](http://http:api.jquery.com/stop/#stop-clearQueue-jumpToEnd) before adjusting `iframe` contents.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this to work by using jQuery's [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) function before reloading the iframe.

```
$('#imageFading',iframe).stop();
```